# Setting the initial scene of OL3-Cesium map in Tilt View

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, cesium

I have two maps.

One of them is using **CesiumJS** library, and the other map is using the **OpenLayers3-Cesium** integration library.

What I need to do is set the initial scene of the maps in `Tilt View`.

I have managed to do so in my `Cesium` map. See code below:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var url='http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms';
var layers=viewer.scene.globe.imageryLayers;
layers.removeAll();
layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
    url:url,
    layers:'ghaziabad_map'
}));

var scene = viewer.scene;
var modelMatrix = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(
    Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(77.567485,28.829527, 0.0));
var model = scene.primitives.add(Cesium.Model.fromGltf({
    url : 'SampleData/models/CesiumGround/modimandir.gltf',
    modelMatrix : modelMatrix
}));
var position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(77.567485,28.829527, 0);
var entity = scene.entities.add({
        position : position
});
viewer.trackedEntity = entity;
Sandcastle.finishedLoading();
```

I want to achieve the same thing now in my second map, using `ol3-cesium`.
My code so far:

```
var source=new ol.source.TileWMS({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
  params:{LAYERS:'ghaziabad_map'}
});
var ol2d = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source:source
    })
  ],
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([72.77469766,18.8907357,72.992294311,19.293357849], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 3
  })
});

var ol3d = new olcs.OLCesium({map: ol2d});
var scene = ol3d.getCesiumScene();
var modelMatrix = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(
    Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(77.567485,28.829527, 0.0));
var model = scene.primitives.add(Cesium.Model.fromGltf({
    url : 'SampleData/models/CesiumGround/modimandir.gltf',
    modelMatrix : modelMatrix
}));

var provider = new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
    layers : 'ghaziabad_map'
});
scene.provider = provider;
```

Comment: It looks like you have answered your own question within that question.  It would be better to [edit] out the answer and make it a proper answer instead.  It is perfectly OK to answer your own question, and may earn you some reputation points to unlock various privileges on this site.

Comment: @PolyGeo this is a perfectly valid question. I am also interested in finding a solution. The first part of the OP's code is written in [ol3-cesium](http://openlayers.org/ol3-cesium/) library, the second part is [cesiumjs](https://cesiumjs.org), a different library. Ratheesh says that it works in the second one, but not in the first one.

Comment: @RaluBur  If you or the asker can [edit] the question to make that clearer and ping me then I will be happy to re-open it.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have edited the question. Feel free to review it and make further edits if needed.